# About the meaning of による (cause or dependency?)

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, usage

I usually see による used as a way to express the cause of something:

> 震災によってたくさんの人の命が失われた。
> There were many people who lost their lives due to the earthquake.

But in some places I see it being used as a way to express dependency on something:

> すべてはそれによるね
> Everything depends on it.

How can I differentiate between those uses?

Comment: Context and practice.  "Their losing their lives depended on the earthquake" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think they can be considered as expressing the same cause-effect (in a rough sense), the difference being the first speaking about the past and the second about the future. Another thing is that English/Japanese phrases are not one-to-one.